# Next and Previous Dynamic Action using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I am trying to make the previous& next button using this code but it displays this error: Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for Execute PL/SQL Code.

```
declare
r_id room.ROOM_ID%type; 
r_type room.ROOM_TYPE%type; 
r_cap room.ROOM_CAP%type; 
r_price room.ROOM_PRICE%type; 
x1 number;

begin
x1:= to_number(:ROWNUMBER,'99');

select ROOM_ID, ROOM_TYPE, ROOM_CAP, ROOM_PRICE into r_id, r_type, r_cap, r_price from (select rownum r, ROOM_ID,ROOM_TYPE,ROOM_CAP,ROOM_PRICE from room) 
where r = x1+1;

:ROOM_ID :=r_id; 
:ROOM_TYPE :=r_type; 
:ROOM_CAP :=r_cap;
:ROOM_PRICE := r_price;
:ROWNUMBER := x1+1;

Exception
when NO_DATA_FOUND then 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data in selected variable');
END;
```

Comment: Pls pay attention to tagging as you are using oracle and not mysql!

Comment: Please include a [MRE] that replicates the problem as there should be no way that this code can raise a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception as you have an exception handling block that is catching that exact error and I cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: As an aside, you are using `ROWNUM` on an unordered set of rows and the data that you get now may be in a different order (if, for example, your database has row movement enabled) from the data that you get in 5 minutes and trying to find the "next" row might give inconsistent results.

Comment: Which tool do you really use? You tagged the question with "Oracle Forms" (might be), but Forms don't have "dynamic actions" - they have "triggers". Oracle Apex has "dynamic actions". So ...? Also, using `dbms_output.put_line` in either of these is useless.